# Ошибка при создании проекта

Tags: c#, xamarin

Я первый раз в жизни создал проект в Xamarin и уже такая ошибка

[image: 1]

в этом коде

```cs
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace Pixel_Complex.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "Pixel_Complex", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
}
```

Я нигде ничего не написал, только нажал <kbd>Начать отладку</kbd>.

---

Что делать?

Comment: Создать класс `App` ?

Comment: @tym32167 А он в начале не должен быть, потому что как бы этот скрипт тоже `Xamarin` создал?

Comment: @tym32167 И если всё таки обязательно то где создать? Тут много скриптов.

Comment: Этого я не знаю, не работаю с Xamarin. Просто сама ошибка, что вы показыаете, говорит об отсутствии того класса.

Comment: @tym32167 Я тоже работал с `C#` но с `Xamarin` первый раз, поэтому не хотел просто создать класс.

Comment: ну вот есть [похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43898891/312041)

Comment: @tym32167 проблема точь в точь что у меня но у меня нет тире в имени. У меня там пробел. Вот имя - `Pixel Complex`

Comment: @tym32167 Второй ответ решает мою проблему. Спасибо.

Comment: Если вы решили проблему, отпишите сюда решение сами :)

Comment: @tym32167 я сейчас не дома. Когда буду опишу.

Comment: @tym32167 Впечатляет?

Comment: норм, поставил поюсик )

Comment: Вот у меня такая же проблема, но мне не помогает ни 1 ни 2 решение...

Comment: @Радион задайте новый вопрос. Опишите вашу проблему. Я сам Xamarin-ом давно не пользовался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### В начале

Это ошибка Visual Studio 2017, и чтобы его исправить мне посоветовали 2 варианты.

---

### Первый вариант

Первый вариант показывает как исправить эту ошибку. Для этого мы заходим в раздел 
"Управление пакетами NuGet".

[image]

И тут обновляем Xamarin.Forms.

[image]

Это по идее должен был мне помочь, но ничего не изменился поэтому я использовал второй вариант.

---

### Второй вариант

Второй вариант пытается не решать, а избегать этой ошибки. Тут мы просто не ставим в имени никакие пробелы, тире или подчёркивания.

[image]

Не стоит беспокоиться насчёт имени проекта, так как он не зависит от этой имени. Имя проекта можно изменить заходя в "Свойства: ...".

[image]

А потом меняем его в разделе "Манифест Android".

[image]